# visual studio 2017 no asp.net templates

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 Community edition.
When I want to make a new project, there is no option to create an ASP.NET application.

What's up with that?

[image: No ASP.NET templates (Web)]

Comment: Did you include web development in your installation?

Comment: I've installed all Workloads/Individual Components.
[link](https://pieterjan.pro/snapshots/screenshot.png)

Comment: @user3582780 no you have not install all, or they have not been installed correctly. When ASP.NET is installed in Projects Templates appears Web section http://take.ms/Zn71S

Comment: [ErrorLog](https://pieterjan.pro/dd_RClientSetup_20170709101809.log)

Comment: I had exactly same issue on one computer. It was, at least on my case, because a Windows Update didn't get installed. There are few mskb articles about that.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Visual Studio Installer , select Community Version Update in the appeared menu select Asp.Net and Install it.

[image]

Comment: Please look at the screenshot i posted:[link](https://pieterjan.pro/snapshots/screenshot.png)